# Javascript Widget JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget, jsonp

I am looking to create a widget similar to the one created by Get Satisfaction (http://getsatisfaction.com/). You can see their widget by clicking on 'Feedback' on the left side of the page.

We would like the user to be setup by copying a bit of JS to their webpage and nothing else.

In its simplest use, a user would open the widget and enter data. This data would be sent to our server (cross domain) for processing and a response sent back to the user.

Can anyone shed some light on how this can be done?

I've read that I can send a JSONP request using jQuery and handle a response callback- can this be encapsulated with injected javascript?

All help greatly welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, JSONP is the correct method for this and should work for your situation. JSONP is basically injecting a `<script>` tag to simulate a GET response, the contents of the script is a callback method with the JSON object inside it. Hense the name, JSON + Padding.

Note: JSONP does obviously not support POST callbacks or custom headers, as it is just a `<script>` tag that gets injected and removed when ready.

Comment: Thanks for your reply CharlesLeaf. I tried implementing a primitive version of JSONP like this example [link](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2682). This worked fine until I tried to package it up in a JS file on an external site. If I cannot do callbacks, it seems like JSONP is not the best method for completing my goal.

Comment: Do you have a sample of what you tried somewhere? Maybe you just made a small mistake somewhere, because the big advantage of JSONP is that it works cross-domain - so ideal in this situation.

Comment: In the clients html page I make a call to a our JS file hosted on our server (http://absolutekack.com/server.js). The body of the clients page has

`<input type="button" id="useJSONP" value="Use JSONP"></input><br /><br />
    <span id="jsonpResult"></span>`
(This can be injected later).

The PHP file does the following:
`if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['callback']))
    {
        $obj->name = $_GET['name'];
        $obj->message = "Hello " . $obj->name;

        echo $_GET['callback']. '(' . json_encode($obj) . ');';
    }`

Comment: Hm, it does perform the JSONP 'request' however the page it requests `http://absolutekack.com/server.php?callback=jsonpCallback&name=Chad` returns an empty document.. Also, note that since it's basically returning a JavaScript file your PHP should return a `Content-Type: text/javascript` header as well. Maybe because `$obj` is undefined?

Comment: CharlesLeaf- I didn't give post the full implementation of server.php. $obj is defined in the code- but I didn't think about the Content-Type- thanks for that.